# Parse JavaScript and keep track of all variables and their values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, parsing, electron

I was watching [Bret Victor's talk "Inventing on Principle"](https://vimeo.com/36579366) the other night and decided to try and build the real time JavaScript editor he demoed. You can see it in action at [18:05](https://vimeo.com/36579366#t=1085s) when he implements binary search.

It doesn't look like he ever released such an editor, but regardless, I thought I could learn a lot building one like it.

Here's what I have so far

[image: nasherai]

What it can currently do:

- Keep track of variables and their values (if assigned as literals)
- Print them on the same line on the right
- Show parsing errors

I'm using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) and [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) to build the app, so it's a desktop app for OSX, but written in JavaScript and HTML.

For parsing, I'm using [Acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn). So far it's a fantastic parser, but it's really hard to actually run the code after it's been parsed. Permitting only literal assignments such as `var x = 1` is doable, but things get really complex fast once you try to do stuff as simple as `var x = 1 + 2`, due to how Acorn structures the parsed result.

I don't want to just `eval` the whole thing, since it's could be dangerous and there's probably better ways to do it.

Ideally, I could find a safe way to evaluate the code on the left and keep track of all the variables somehow. Unfortunately, my research indicates that there is no access to private variables in JavaScript, so I'm hoping I can count on fellow developers' ingenuity to help me with this. Any hints on how to do this better/easier than with Acorn would be greatly appreciated.

If you need it, my code base is here: https://github.com/dchacke/nasherai

Comment: I think you should make you question shorter. It can be summarized in one sentence. *How do I safely evaluate arbitrary strings in node.js?* (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: you should use eval, that's what's it for. heck, khan uses with+eval for their real-time-editor. this is your code you're eval'ing, not an anon submit, there is no risk whatsoever.

Comment: @dandavis No he should definitely not use eval. What if the user erases the hard drive by running a system command?

Comment: @Oleander: eval() can easily be blocked from require() or any other lexical entities in "use strict", but why would the user be logged in as root and running a command that would do such a thing in the first place? if you want to break stuff, there's much easier ways, and i don't see how your sandbox link sanitizes any actual commands, it only prevents lexical pollution as far as i can tell from the source, and the shovel script is even worse because it uses the impossible-to-restrict Function() instead of eval().

Comment: @dandavis Or you could just be safe and use a sandbox.

Comment: @Oleander: I'm confused, how would a sandbox (like the one you link) help protect against your first scenario: accidentally wiping the hard drive? i'm pretty sure it would not, but maybe you know something i don't? JS uses ref-based security, and that script hides no refs, so i could still `require("fs").beEvil()`...

Comment: @dandavis I think it's easier if you just read the documentation I posted in my answer.

Comment: @Oleander: ok, i looked into it deeper (runInContext) , and while it won't stop hackers, it will likely stop accidental harmful commands, touchè... that said, i think that browser JS is the far safer route, since client-side JS can't even reach the hard drive in the first place, and he's using angular, so obvious a client-side eval() is possible...

Comment: @dandavis The client code when using Electron can access everything node can so `eval` is still not a good idea.

Comment: good point. afaik, only require would need blocked since the core won't let you hurt any files. maybe Electron provides file system commands too, not used it yet, but i'll check it out...

Comment: @Oleander It's about how to safely evaluate arbitrary strings, and it's also about how do keep track of what's happening in memory. I need a good way of finding what variables are being declared, what their values are, when they change, etc, so that I can reliably draw the preview on the right. Doing that using Acorn is *theoretically* possible, but it would be a pain in the ass. I'm just curious if anybody can think of better ways.

Comment: you NEED to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4sSldXv_S4, where resig basically explains how to do exactly what you're going for.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis, that video is super helpful.

Comment: you might also look into coffeescript's guts, which does all that lexical extraction and hoisting, and has a relatively simple and well-commented parser. good for figuring out certain problems if not downright copyable...

Answer (score 1):

Try [sandbox](http://gf3.github.io/sandbox/) for safe evaluation of strings.

```
var s = new Sandbox()
s.run( '1 + 1 + " apples"', function( output ) {
  // output.result == "2 apples"
})
```